# LINQ to SQL, Insertion not working

Tags: c#, linq

I am trying to add record to database using LINQ. This is what I have done so far.

**Working:** 
When I view data after Insertion calls, records are visible in GridDataView but aren't visible in the database.

```
private void button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Add new Song.
    Accessor.InsertSong(1, "Song Name", 1, 1, new TimeSpan(0, 3, 30), 2000);

    dataGridView1.DataSource = Accessor.GetSongTable();
}
```

In Accessor.cs

```
public static void InsertSong(int SongID, string SongName, int AlbumID, int ArtistID, TimeSpan Duration, int TrackNumber)
{
    DataClasses1DataContext dc = new DataClasses1DataContext();

    var matchedSong = (from c in dc.GetTable<Song>()
                       where c.SongID == SongID
                       select c).SingleOrDefault();

    if (matchedSong == null)
    {
        try
        {
            Table<Song> songs = Accessor.GetSongTable();
            Song sng = new Song(SongID, SongName, AlbumID, ArtistD, Duration, TrackNumber);

            songs.InsertOnSubmit(sng);
            songs.Context.SubmitChanges();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
    }
}

public static System.Data.Linq.Table<Song> GetSongTable()
{
    DataClasses1DataContext dc = new DataClasses1DataContext();
    return dc.GetTable<Song>();
}
```

Comment: Why are you mixing different DataContext's?

Comment: you mean songs.Context and DataClasses1DataContext ?

Comment: So... what happens when you debug it? Is it inserted?

Comment: @Tim No it's not. I can see the insertion in GridVew but when I switch to database, no insertion is done there.

Comment: But i mean when you step through the code. Each of those lines executes without error? Including the InsertOnSubmit and SubmitChanges?

Comment: @Tim, there is no error(syntax). Every thing gets executed and works fine. The problem is that database doesn't reflect changes

Answer (score 0):

You context is hosed.  This single context should do the trick.  Always use a using statement when you have a datacontext class.

```
 using (var dc = new DataClasses1DataContext())    {

    var matchedSong = (from c in dc.GetTable<Song>()
                       where c.SongID == SongID
                       select c).SingleOrDefault();

    if (matchedSong == null)
    {
        try
        {
            var song = dc.Song.Create();
            song.SongID = SongID;
            song.SongName = SongName;
            //...
            dc.Song.Add(song);
            dc.SubmitChanges();
            }
        } }
```

My EF is a little rusty, you may not need to do the last dc.Song.Add(song) command.  Not sure.